# How to change a span's content when other element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

I am looking to change the content of this span tag:

```
<span class="ui-btn-text" id="btnText">Read how we have helped</span>
```

To:

```
<span class="ui-btn-text" id="btnText">Hide Story</span>
```

This is what I got so far:

```
$('#storyBtn').click(function() {
        $('#story-body').slideToggle('fast', function() {
            $('#btnTextShow').hide();
            $('#btnTextHide').show();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a great example on how to achieve this:
First look at the [**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MtB4V/1/)

Let's see what we have here:

```
$('.ui-btn-text:eq(1)').hide();

$('#storyBtn').click(function() {
    $("#story-body").slideToggle(400);
    $(".ui-btn-text").toggle(300);
});
```

And the html:

```
<div id="storyBtn">
    <span class="ui-btn-text">Read how we have helped</span>
    <span class="ui-btn-text">Hide Story</span>
</div>

<div id="story-body">
    A long,...<br> long time ago...
</div>
```

INFO:

As you can see I simplified and removed all the unnecessary ID's and codes JUST TO MAKE VISIBLE HOW SIMPLE CAN ALL BE. You can redo this changes of mine.

Comment: Thanks! roXon this helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to update the text of the span ... if so try this ->

```
<span class="ui-btn-text" id="btnText">Read how we have helped</span>

   $('#storyBtn').click(function() {
            $('#story-body').slideToggle('fast', function() {
                $('#btnText').text("Hide Story");
                $('#btnTextShow').hide();
                $('#btnTextHide').show();
            });
        });
```

*Untested

Comment: It was not 2 spans. It was 1 span with two different texts. Of course it is better to have two spans, but one has to be hidden when loading

Comment: OK - i have updated to update the content only - but the show() and hide() functions the OP was using led me to believe they were using 2 spans ....

Comment: Ahh ok - on reading it again ... seems the show and hide should be there ... along with the updating of the text ....